# Como ter os recursos de compilação de apk do Flutter no Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, kotlin, ide

No Flutter tem como rodar/testar o apk simulando um smartphone no próprio sistema operacional abrindo uma janela ou abrindo uma aba no navegador.

Tem como fazer isso no kotlin?
existe alguma extensão do android studio ou configuração pra isso?
Ate agora no Kotlin so consigo compilar usando emulador como bluestack ou no celular físico por cabo ou wifi, além do próprio android studio.
Mas a maneira do flutter era bem mais rápida e melhor.

assim é no flutter e que queria que essas opções aparecesse no Kotlin:

[image: como é no flutter]

E assim é no Kotlin:

[image: menu de opções da run do Kotlin]

Answer (score 0):

Sua pergunta parte de uma premissa errada:

> [...] rodar/testar o apk simulando um smartphone no próprio sistema operacional abrindo uma janela ou abrindo uma aba no navegador. [...]

Não é bem isso que ocorre. [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/) é um framework desenvolvido pela Google para desenvolver aplicações multi-plataformas.

Isto é, com um mesmo código em Flutter, você pode gerar um aplicativo para Android, um aplicativo para iOS, uma página web, e (ainda em beta) aplicações desktop.

Ou seja, quando você seleciona a opção de destino "Chrome", você **não está** gerando um apk e rodando ele no navegador: você está pegando o mesmo código Flutter e gerando uma build diferente. Uma que o seu navegador compreende e que não é um APK. APK's são para aplicações android.

Para aplicações web, quando roda-se o comando `flutter build web` uma pasta inteira é gerada como output dentro do diretório `build/web`. Essa pasta é a que deve ser hospedada em um servidor para publicar seu site. Em contrapartida, quando roda-se o comando `flutter build apk`, um APK é gerado para ser enviado à loja de aplicativos Google Play. (Embora hoje em dia o conceito de app bundle [seja preferido](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#building-the-app-for-release) nesse caso)

Tudo isso é possível por Flutter ser multi-plataforma e disponibilizar builds para Web e Desktop. Quando você abre um projeto Android (e falando dessa maneira acaba ficando mais evidente), você está abrindo exatamente isso: um projeto *Android*. Não existe a opção de rodar e compilar em outros destinos porque este projeto não faz isso. Um projeto Android tem como destino algo que esteja rodando o sistema operacional Android. Seja um emulador no seu computador, ou um dispositivo físico conectado.

Comment: E, como um adendo, essa é justamente uma das principais vantagens que motiva as pessoas a usarem Flutter. Ao invés de desenvolver a mesma aplicação diversas vezes, uma para cada destino, com Flutter você pode reaproveitar grande parte do código e desenvolver todas ao mesmo tempo. Outro exemplo de vantagem seria o Hot Reload ou Hot Restart, que torna o fluxo de desenvolvimento mais rápido e é possível graças a um recurso da linguagem Dart. Por último, destaco que outros Frameworks e linguagens também possuem essas características. Flutter, com Dart não são os únicos.